# Spinner inside ScrollView is closing when opened programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-spinner, android-scrollview

I have form-like layout with some `EditText` rows. Last row is `Spinner`. I wanted to open drawer menu when `Done` button is tapped in last `EditText`. But behavior is weird. Everytime I tap `Done` it opens drawer menu for a fraction of a second and menu closes immediately after. Do you know any solution. I think that `ScrollView` causing some issues. Because I'm using same functionality in another layout without `ScrollView` and it is working fine.

```
//hide keyboard and auto-open dropdown menu on last EditText in form
editText?.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
        editText?.let { app.hideKeyboard(it) }
        spinner?.performClick()
    }
    true
}

fun hideKeyboard(view: View){
        val imm = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I've used `CustomSpinner` from tutorial and I wanted to listen to open event and hide keyboard after that. And its still closing that dropdown menu. I don't really know what can cause this. Tried manually scroll down to bottom and still same issue.

**UPDATE - SOLUTION**

I had to create handlers for fullscroll of the `ScrollView` to the very bottom of it and also I had to put `spinner.performClick()` inside handler, because hiding keyboard is changing screen height and `ScrollView` will close options menu till keyboard is finally hidden.

That means delaying fullscroll and performclick will not close options menu.

Code:

```
editText?.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, _ ->
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                v?.apply {
                    clearFocus()
                    app.hideKeyboard(this)
                    post(delay = 200){scrollView?.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)}
                }
                post(delay = 200) {spinner?.performClick()}
            }
            true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try scrolling to the spinner before opening it.

```
editText?.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
        editText?.let { app.hideKeyboard(it) }
        spinner?.let {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                scrollView?.scrollToDescendant(it)
            } else {
                scrollView?.scrollTo(0, it.getBottom())
            }
            it.performClick()
        }
    }
    true
}
```

Comment: Already tried this before. Same issue. But I found out if I call performClick() without hiding a keyboard, drawer stays visible. It has something to do with hiding keyboard which triggers close event for spinner. And editText?.clearFocus() did not close keyboard

Comment: Your code works properly for me when I use `scrollTo`, Are you sure you're using `scrollTo` and not `smoothScrollTo`? I still feel like the most likely reason that the spinner closes is because the `ScrollView` is in motion.

Comment: Yes, I copy-pasted your code and it still doesn't work :(